# Nasm - Winapi functions that do not pop their parameters

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, calling-convention, msvcrt

I was writing a program in Nasm and I found out that while winapi functions like `CreateProcessA` or `GetModuleFileNameA` do pop their arguments from the stack once they have finished, `printf` is not doing that.

Is there a reason for that? And more importently: are there any other winapi functions who do not pop the elements from the stack? Because my program is misbehaving and I want to be sure that none of it is caused by not pop'd values.

Comment: Assuming 32-bit code -Because `printf` is not part of the WinApi (which uses STDCALL calling convention where the function cleans up the parameters on the stack). `printf` It is part of the MSVC runttime library, and there the default calling convention is CDECL Basically if you are calling the C library functions or are calling code generated by MSVC/C++ then you wants CDECL calling convention as describe here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=vs-2019 . Additional info is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

99% percent of exported Windows functions use the [stdcall calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall). On 32-bit x86 this creates smaller more efficient code because the callee restores the stack.

Functions that take a variable number of arguments cannot use stdcall because only the caller knows how many arguments there are and therefore the caller has to restore the stack.

`printf` is not a Windows function, it is a C library function and most of the C library uses the [cdecl calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=vs-2019) where the caller restores the stack. The Windows provided print functions like [`wsprintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-wsprintfa) are also cdecl. You can assume that any API function ending with `...` as the final parameter uses cdecl.

Comment: "*You can assume that any API function ending with `...` as the final parameter uses cdecl*" - and you can assume that any Win32 API function uses `stdcall` unless documented otherwise.